# Postgres, Postgis (ST_DWithin and radius)

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis

I have a request that looks like this

```
     const query = `SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(position)::json as position
     FROM shops
     WHERE ST_DWithin(
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${_user.position.coordinates[0]}, ${
       _user.position.coordinates[1]
     }), 4326)::geography,
        position,
        ${user.radius * 1000}
     );`;
```

And there is a store on the map (which is exactly within the radius of the circle on Google maps). However, when updating the user's position, I don't get the nearest store within that radius. (But if you get a little closer, the store appears)

```
I store position data as
   @Column({
     type: 'geography',
     spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
     srid: 4326,
     nullable: true
   })
   position: Point;
```

I've tried to use this

```
    const query = `SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(position)::json as position
    FROM shops
    WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(${_user.position.coordinates[0]}, ${
      _user.position.coordinates[1]
    })::geography, ST_SetSRID(position::geometry, 4326)::geography, ${
      _user.radius * 1000
    });`;
```

But it works as code above

I understand that there are some changes in the geography and geometry of the circle, but it is unlikely that this can affect a circle with a radius of one kilometer

the picture shows that this is the maximum distance at which I can get this store

[image]

But in this picture, the store is not included in the radius of the circle, but gets the store from the database

[image]

**Update:**

I use user coordinates like

```
{
    position: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
                50.444327898,
                30.505305436
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the coordinates you are using?

Comment: A swap between latitude and longitude could explain such strangeness.

Comment: I've already swapped them, but it doesn't look like it should be.

Comment: @HERONAX without the coordinates it is hard to say for sure why your system is behaving like this. My guess would be either a SRS mismatch or the classic x,y swap

Comment: This is due to inaccuracies of the buffer circle coordinates; *at best* this circle is created with *spherical* projection of the center point, but more likely by choosing an appropriate UTM projection (FYI: the latter is the default behavior in PostGIS if passed a `GEOGRAPHY` type to `ST_Buffer`) and simple *planar Cartesian* translation. `ST_DWithin` however, if passed a `GEOGRAPHY` type, measures on the *spheroid* by default - even more complex, even more precise. You can try to set its fourth parameter to `"use_spheroid" := FALSE`, but I doubt that it makes a difference at this scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem after a while. I started using ST_Distance to get the nearest stores.
I actually made a mistake when I swapped the length and width of both the user and the store. So now the solution looks like this

```
    const query = `
    SELECT *,
           ST_AsGeoJSON(position)::json as position,
           ST_Distance(
               ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${_user.position.coordinates[1]}, ${
      _user.position.coordinates[0]
    }), 4326)::geography,
      ST_MakePoint(ST_Y(position::geometry), ST_X(position::geometry))
    ) as distanceToUser
    FROM shops
    WHERE ST_Distance(
      ST_MakePoint(ST_Y(position::geometry), ST_X(position::geometry)),
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${_user.position.coordinates[1]}, ${
      _user.position.coordinates[0]
    }), 4326)::geography
  ) <= ${_user.radius * 1000}
    ORDER BY distanceToUser;
    `;
```